# Pythonで[1,2,2,3,3,3]のようなリストから[1,2,3]のようなリストを作成するには、どのように記述すれば実現できるのでしょうか。

Tags: python, python3

下記のような要素の値分だけ要素があるリストXがあり、これから要素の値を１つずつにしたリストYを作成するにはどのような記述方法がありますでしょうか。

```
# 元のリスト
X=[4,4,4,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1,3,3,3]

# 変換後のリスト
Y=[4,3,6,2,1,3]
```

2日間考え、調べましたがわかりませんでした。
リスト内包表記などを使うのかなと思っています。

わかる方いましたらご教授願います。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 順番も保持しておきたいということなんでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

順番を保持しておきたいです。
重複と書いてしまいましたが、
要素の値分ある要素をそれぞれ１つずつにしたいです。
[1,2,2,4,4,4,4,2,2,1]なら[1,2,4,2,1]のようにです。

（すみません！2番目にコメントしていただいた方の投稿を削除してしまったかもしれません。大変失礼しました。内容は確認済みです。）

Comment: 大丈夫です。いくつか記事を紹介したのですが、考え方の間違いに気付いて自分で削除しました。で、要望に沿うであろう回答を書きましたよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最初に現れた`3,3,3`と後に現れた`3,3,3`を別物として扱いたい場合は、こちらの記事の`itertools.groupby()`とリスト内包表記が使えるでしょう。
[Pythonでリストの連続する同じ値の要素をグループ化（itertools.groupby）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-itertools-groupby/)

```
import itertools

X = [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1,3,3,3]
Y = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(X)]
print(Y)
```

Comment: kunifさんありがとうございます！
itertoolsについて初めて知りました。
解決しました！大変助かりました！

Answer (score 2):

[more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) の [unique_justseen](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_justseen) を使う方法もあります。

```py
from more_itertools import unique_justseen

X = [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1,3,3,3]
Y = [*unique_justseen(X)]

print(Y)

# [4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
大変勉強になります。

Answer (score 1):

プログラミングには、Set(集合: 重複なし)とOrderedSet(順序保持集合)というものがあり、
質問の要件を満たすOrderedSetをPythonで行うには、以下のようにできるようです。

https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-orderedset-in-python

```py
from sortedcollections import OrderedSet

x = [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1,3,3,3]

y = OrderedSet(x)

print(y)
```

順序保持が不要であれば以下のようにできるはずです。

```py
x = [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,1,3,3,3]

y = set(x)

print(y)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

言葉にしづらいのですが、
要素の値分あるかたまりを１つにしたいのです。
[1,2,2,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,2,2]なら[1,2,4,2,1,2]のようにしたいです。

重複というのは適切ではありませんでした。申し訳ございません。